# Turn Street Address Into Components

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, street-address

I have address data I extracted from SQL, and have now loaded into R.  I am trying to extract out the individual components, namely the ZIP-CODE at the end of the query (State would also be nice).  I would like the ZIP-CODE and State to be in new individual columns.

The primary issue is the ZIP-CODE is sometimes 5 digits, and sometimes 9.

Two example rows would be:

```
Address_FULL
1234 NOWHERE ST WASHINGTON DC 20005
567 EVERYWHERE LN CHARLOTTE NC 22011-1203
```

I suspect I'll need some kind of regex `\\d{5}` notation, or some kind of fancy manipulation in dplyr that I'm not aware exists.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Be very careful using regular expressions to parse addresses. This article explains the problems that can arise from parsing with regular expressions. https://smartystreets.com/articles/regular-expressions-for-street-addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the zip code is always at the end you could use

```
str_extract(Address_FULL,"[[:digit:]]{5}(-[[:digit:]]{4})?$")
```

To add a "zip" column via `dplyr` you could use

```
df %>% mutate(zip = str_extract(Address_FULL,"[[:digit:]]{5}(-[[:digit:]]{4})?$"))
```

Where `df` is your dataframe containing Address_FULL and 
`str_extract()` is from `stringr`.

State could be extracted as follows:

```
str_extract(Address_FULL,"(?<=\\s)[[:alpha:]]{2}(?=\\s[[:digit:]]{5})")
```

However, **this makes the following assumptions**:

1. The state abbreviation is 2 characters long
2. The state abbreviation is followed immediately by a space
3. The zip code follows immediately after the space that follows the state

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the zip is always at the end, you can try:

```
tail(unlist(strsplit(STRING, split=" ")), 1)
```

For example

```
ex1 = "1234 NOWHERE ST WASHINGTON DC 20005"
ex2 = "567 EVERYWHERE LN CHARLOTTE NC 22011-1203"

> tail(unlist(strsplit(ex1, split=" ")), 1)
[1] "20005"

> tail(unlist(strsplit(ex2, split=" ")), 1)
[1] "22011-1203"
```

Comment: That actually works pretty well since the splitter is always a space.  I can then do the same for extracting the state.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use my package `tfwstring`

Works automatically on any address type, even with prefixes and suffixes.

```
if (!require(remotes)) install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("nbarsch/tfwstring")
```

```
parseaddress("1234 NOWHERE ST WASHINGTON DC 20005", force_stateabb = F)
```

```
     AddressNumber         StreetName StreetNamePostType          PlaceName          StateName            ZipCode 
            "1234"          "NOWHERE"               "ST"       "WASHINGTON"               "DC"            "20005"
```

```
parseaddress("567 EVERYWHERE LN CHARLOTTE NC 22011-1203", force_stateabb = F)
```

```
     AddressNumber         StreetName StreetNamePostType          PlaceName          StateName            ZipCode 
             "567"       "EVERYWHERE"               "LN"        "CHARLOTTE"               "NC"       "22011-1203"
```